# subscript out of bounds error datatable

Tags: r, data.table

I have a simple data frame as follows:

```
 hai_dispense_number hai_atc date_of_claim hai_age
1                  tom    A10A    2011-11-01      42
2                  tom    A10B    2011-11-01      42
3                  tom    G10R    2011-11-01      42
4                  tom    A10A    2012-02-02      42
5                  tom    A10A    2012-04-03      42
6                 mary    A10A    2012-02-02      36
7                 mary    A10A    2012-03-02      36
8                 mary    G123    2012-03-02      36
9                 mary    E123    2012-05-02      36
10                mary    T123    2012-07-02      36
11                mary    A10A    2012-08-02      43
12                 sue   GR123    2012-03-02      43
13                 sue   GR123    2012-03-08      43
14                 sue   GR123    2012-09-03      43
15                 sue   GR123    2012-10-01      43
16                 sue   GR123    2012-03-02      43
17                 pat    A10A    2012-01-02      52
18                 pat   GR123    2011-11-12      52
19                 pat    A10A    2012-03-03      52
20                 pat   GR123    2012-01-01      52
21                 pat    A10A    2012-05-06      52
```

I want to isolate people who had the code A10A only from 2012-01-01 onwards, and not in 2011. There are some people in the above dataframe who did not have the code A10A at any stage and so I'd like to get rid of them too.  So in the end, I want to have data only for pat and mary. Here is how I do it:

Step 1: Assigns the "index date". In other words the first date in 2012 that someone got the code A10A

```
dt2<- data.table(dff,key=c('hai_dispense_number','date_of_claim'))
dt2[,date_of_claim := as.Date(date_of_claim)]
dt2[grepl('^A10A*?', as.character(dt2$hai_atc))& between(date_of_claim,as.Date("2012-01-01"),as.Date("2012-12-31")),
    index := as.character(min(date_of_claim))
    ,   by=c('hai_dispense_number','hai_atc')]  #
dt2$index<-as.Date(dt2$index, origin='1970-01-01')
dt2$hai_atc<-as.character(dt2$hai_atc)
```

Step 2: Creating the index date creates some NA values for rows that were not A10A or occurred before 2012-01. I need to fill in this NA value with each person's unique index date. This code usually works, but for reason with these data, I keep getting an error

```
dt2[, index := index[!is.na(index)][[1]], by=hai_dispense_number]  ##gives the index date for each person to each of their individual rows of data

Error in index[!is.na(index)][[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Steps 3, 4 and 5: I usually can follow on from here, and find out who had a code A10A in 2011 and then exclude them. But my process is being interrupted by the above error.

I looked at this page: [Subscript out of bounds - general definition and solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031338/subscript-out-of-bounds-general-definition-and-solution) and tried running the tests they recommend: but it doesn't look like i have extra rows for the variable index. Perhaps I'm not testing properly.

If anyone can shed any light on why the above is happening I would be really grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want much easier by using the `any` function. With `any(hai_atc=="A10A")` you create a logical vector for all people having `A10A` and with `!any(hai_atc=="A10A" & year(date_of_claim) == 2011)` you update that vecor for the ones who have that code in the year 2011 to `FALSE`. With `[idx==TRUE]` you filter just the cases you need and with `[,idx:=NULL]` you remove the `idx` column:

```
newDT <- DT[, idx := any(hai_atc=="A10A") & !any(hai_atc=="A10A" & year(date_of_claim) == 2011),
            by = hai_dispense_number
            ][idx==TRUE][,idx:=NULL]
```

this results in:

```
> newDT
    hai_dispense_number hai_atc date_of_claim hai_age
 1:                mary    A10A    2012-02-02      36
 2:                mary    A10A    2012-03-02      36
 3:                mary    G123    2012-03-02      36
 4:                mary    E123    2012-05-02      36
 5:                mary    T123    2012-07-02      36
 6:                mary    A10A    2012-08-02      43
 7:                 pat    A10A    2012-01-02      52
 8:                 pat   GR123    2011-11-12      52
 9:                 pat    A10A    2012-03-03      52
10:                 pat   GR123    2012-01-01      52
11:                 pat    A10A    2012-05-06      52
```

---

In response to your comment: You might want to use single square brackets (i.e.: `[ ]`) like `dt2[, index := index[!is.na(index)][1], by=hai_dispense_number]`. Furthermore, your code can be simplified to:

```
dt2 <- data.table(mydf,key=c('hai_dispense_number','date_of_claim'))
dt2[, date_of_claim := as.Date(date_of_claim)]
dt2[grepl('^A10A*?', hai_atc) & between(date_of_claim, as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-12-31")),
    index := min(date_of_claim), by=.(hai_dispense_number,hai_atc)]

dt2[, index := index[!is.na(index)][1], by=hai_dispense_number]
```

However, this gives not the result as you described:

```
> dt2
    hai_dispense_number hai_atc date_of_claim hai_age      index
 1:                mary    A10A    2012-02-02      36 2012-02-02
 2:                mary    A10A    2012-03-02      36 2012-02-02
 3:                mary    G123    2012-03-02      36 2012-02-02
 4:                mary    E123    2012-05-02      36 2012-02-02
 5:                mary    T123    2012-07-02      36 2012-02-02
 6:                mary    A10A    2012-08-02      43 2012-02-02
 7:                 pat   GR123    2011-11-12      52 2012-01-02
 8:                 pat   GR123    2012-01-01      52 2012-01-02
 9:                 pat    A10A    2012-01-02      52 2012-01-02
10:                 pat    A10A    2012-03-03      52 2012-01-02
11:                 pat    A10A    2012-05-06      52 2012-01-02
12:                 sue   GR123    2012-03-02      43       <NA>
13:                 sue   GR123    2012-03-02      43       <NA>
14:                 sue   GR123    2012-03-08      43       <NA>
15:                 sue   GR123    2012-09-03      43       <NA>
16:                 sue   GR123    2012-10-01      43       <NA>
17:                 tom    A10A    2011-11-01      42 2012-02-02
18:                 tom    A10B    2011-11-01      42 2012-02-02
19:                 tom    G10R    2011-11-01      42 2012-02-02
20:                 tom    A10A    2012-02-02      42 2012-02-02
21:                 tom    A10A    2012-04-03      42 2012-02-02
```

The reason why you are not getting the desired result with your code is that you are not excluding the groups which have `A10A` in 2011. The `any` function is specifically designed to achieve logical operations as described by you.

Furthermore, by using the `any` function you can achieve the desired result in a simpler way. And that is also applicable for more complex datasets. It's also not a problem to use `grepl` inside `any`:

```
newDT2 <- DT[, idx := any(grepl('^A10A*?', hai_atc)) & !any(grepl('^A10A*?', hai_atc) & year(date_of_claim) == 2011),
             by = hai_dispense_number
             ][idx==TRUE][,idx:=NULL]
```

which gives the same result:

```
> identical(newDT, newDT2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hi Japp, thanks for the answer and the "any" suggestion. I'd like to stick to the code i have though as the real dataset is actually a bit more complex and the codes are much longer than A10A. So want to keep using "grepl" for this reason, in addition to a more complex date problem with isn't just about excluding 2011 dates. I put up a simplistic version of the dataset here to try get help with the error. Do you have any idea why the code I'm using to repeat each person's unique index date isn't working here? I've used it before without a problem but I can't figure out whats going on here.

Comment: the single brackets work. Such a simple solution - thank you. I'll get playing around with "any" and my dates to see if I can get it to do what I want. You're right - your code is much simpler. Thank you again! Why was it that the double brackets didn't work?

Comment: @user2363642 [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the) for a more thorough discussion about the difference between `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`