# R: Subscript out of bounds when using tm function Corpus on LexisNexis-data

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I'm trying to create a corpus of articles from LexisNexis with the `tm`-package.
The articles have been exported from LexisNexis as .html and are parsed into R with the `tm.plugin.lexisnexis`-package like so:

```
> library("tm")
> library("tm.plugin.lexisnexis")
> src <- LexisNexisSource("~/Desktop/lexisnexis.html")
```

Following the instructions in the `tm.plugin.lexisnexis`-documentation, I then create a corpus using the `tm`-package, like so:

```
> data <- Corpus(src, readerControl = list(language = NA))
Error in getNodeSet(tree, "//div[@class = 'c3']/p[@class = 'c1']/span[@class = 'c4']")[[1]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Example html-data: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2353143/lexisnexis.html)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand. Am I missing something in my .html-file or is the `src`-object incomplete?

Comment: Not sure what is going on there. Please look for general solution of the above error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031338/subscript-out-of-bounds-general-definition-and-solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the package. It's currently broken as the format used by LexisNexis is undocumented. I'll try to fix it, but if anybody proposes a patch, it will happen sooner. :-)