# Error in R code for Marshal Olkin Bivariate Exponential distribution

Tags: r

What does this error mean?

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, 1, value = 0.0225315561703551) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 1):

This error code means you are trying to index your variable outside its range. Example so if you had an array `x <- c(1,2,3)` and you were wanted `x[4]`, or tried to call `x[3.14]`.

1. *Check your code*, To *debug* in Rstudio, I put `browser()` statements in where I want code to stop and then step through the process.
2. Check how you are *indexing any loops*. I noticed it is complaining about `i`
3. *Update your package* you are using for calc. You can sometimes run into gremlins that have been fixed in later versions.
4. This may be helpful: [Subscript out of bounds - general definition and solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031338/subscript-out-of-bounds-general-definition-and-solution)