# (R Igraph) Using affilliation to create subgraph from adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I need to create a subgraph from an adjacency matrix selecting by affiliation data. How do I match an adjacency and an affiliation matrix?

Take the following adjacency matrix:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
A   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
B   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
C   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
D   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
E   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
F   1   1   0   1   1   0   1
G   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

And the following affiliation matrix:

```
    P   R   Q
A   1   1   0
B   1   0   1
C   1   1   0
D   0   1   0
E   1   0   1
F   0   0   1
G   1   1   0
```

How do I create a subgraph from the adjacency matrix only with the nodes corresponding to P in the affiliation matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to:

- filter out nodes from your adjacency matrix where the corresponding `P` is `1` in the affiliation matrix
- convert filtered adjacency matrix to an `igraph` object

then you can accomplish that with the following:

```
# the names(which()) isn't needed for the subset of adj
p_nodes <- names(which(aff[,"P"] == 1))
p_adj   <- adj[p_nodes, p_nodes]

p_graph <- igraph::graph.adjacency(p_graph)
```

Comment: Adam, these codes work for the small test matrices in the original question, but not for my large, real matrices of 867 nodes. The error I'm getting is "Error in adj[P_nodes, P_nodes] : subscript out of bounds". 

You know what may be the problem? The large matrices work perfectly fine on their own, but haven't been able to combine them.

Comment: you get that error when you reference an index that doesnt exist (i.e. `x <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2); colnames(x) <- c("a","b"); x[,"c"]` or `matrix(1:4, nrow=2)[3,3]`.  double check that whatever the definition of `P_nodes` is makes sense in the context of `adj`

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the response. I changed the names of the nodes to "name1", "name2",... "name867", but left the matrices otherwise untouched -- and the codes now work. This means that the problem was not the inexistence of the index. Any clue what the problem may be? Cheers.

Comment: glad you got it working. you can see this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031338/subscript-out-of-bounds-general-definition-and-solution) if you want to follow up more on your error,  but without your data it would be hard to make a guess as to what caused the error in your case