# plot.ts subscript out of bounds error

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am trying to plot a timeseries graph with plot.ts, but an error of `Error in dn[[2L]] : subscript out of bounds` happened....

```
revenue_quar <- c(17.37094, 15.58824, 23.79257, 15.44293, 24.75871, 28.68056, 24.32584, 25.59313, 34.66942, 19.94382, 22.35166, 32.10879, 18.76543, 25.99338, 30.31429, 22.81155, 28.05085, 30.76923, 33.29787, 19.04181, 18.00000, 41.07843, 28.94161, 35.35533, 35.46053, 25.79848, 40.41284, 38.00341, 32.37024, 51.25000, 26.57895, 21.40000, 45.84746, 48.42466, 46.99063, 47.20994, 45.12469, 33.32117, 32.36655, 30.24096, 34.58944, 42.74405, 35.49383, 34.76802, 42.01131, 42.47948, 39.83083, 41.15385)
revenue_quar_ts <- ts(revenue_quar, frequency=4, start=c(2004,4))
plot.ts <- revenue_quar_ts
```

I have read [zx8754's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031338/subscript-out-of-bounds-general-definition-and-solution) but still couldn't really understand it... Could you please tell me the solution of fixing this error? Thanks!

Comment: Your MWE seems to work...

Comment: LOL this is interesting... I actually generated the subject by tapply. But then I make it an array using c(), the code works again..... 

Many thanks tho....