# How can I solve the issue that VIF doesn't work after added more variables?

Tags: r

I created ordered logit models using polr in RStudio and the using the vif. It worked fine and I got my results.
But after I decided toadd more variables such as **dummy for age groups, education and income groups**. But when I then use vif I got the error about subscript out of bound

My used data for this:
Here is an example of my data set:

| Work less | lifestatisfied | country | Work much |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 8 | GB | 1 |
| 1 | 8 | SE | 0 |
| 0 | 9 | DK | 1 |
| 0 | 9 | DE | 1 |
| NA | 5 | NO | NA |

continued:

| health | education | income | age | marital status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | Na | 61 | NA |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 30 | NA |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 39 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 | 5 | 52 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 17 | 5 |

- gender is dummy 1 or 2
- age is respondents age like 35, 47 etc.
- income is scaled and is 1 to 10
- educ (education) is 1 to 7
- health is scaled 1 to 5
- work less is dummy i.e. 1 or 0
- work much is dummy, i.e. 1 or 0
- marital status is scaled 1 to 6
- **lifesatisfied is the dependent variable and is scaled 0 to 10.**

My ordered regression model:

```
myorderedmodel = polr(factor(lifesatisfied, ordered = TRUE) ~ maritalstatus + gender + age + age20_29 + age30_39 + age40_49 + age50_59 + income + lowincome + avgincome + highincome + noeducation + loweducation + higheducation + health + child + religion + workless + workmuch, data = mydata, method = "logistic", Hess = TRUE)

vif(myorderedmodel)
```

Gives the following error:

```
Error in R[subs, subs] : subscript out of bounds
```

I really didn't understand the error. What does it mean? And how can it be solved?

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031338/subscript-out-of-bounds-general-definition-and-solution>. This could be helpful.

Comment: @TarJae thanks for you comment! I actually saw this yesterday but I really didn't understand anything of if.. it is too much technical and complicated for me to understand

Comment: Using the summary() and Anova() works fine.. but using vif gives `Error in R[subs, subs] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: is there a limit of how many variables that can be used in `vif()`

Comment: if I for instance remove all the dummary variables for age groups i created then it works.. anyone knows why? I would really wanted to keep the age groups in my regression