# Error in files[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception

It shows subscript out of bound and then error in tmp . How to resolve this

> data <- list()
> for (i in 1:length(files)) {
> data[[i]] <- readRDS(files[[i]])
> }
> Error in files[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
> names(data) <- names
> for (i in 1:length(files)) {data[[i]][["sample"]] <- names[[i]]}
> **Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
> **> names(data) <- names
> library(future)
> plan("multicore", workers = 16)
> options(future.globals.maxSize = 2000 * 1024^2)
> library(ggplot2)
> anchors <- FindIntegrationAnchors(object.list = data, dims = 1:20)
> Computing 2000 integration features
> Error in `*tmp*`[[ii]] :
> attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

I am running scRNASeq pipeline and got this error in the beginning steps

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. You might want to show the portion of code where you are getting the error. I'm guessing you're using R. It seems that somewhere in your code you are trying to access a position in list or an array that exceeds its size.

Comment: Check this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031338/subscript-out-of-bounds-general-definition-and-solution)